# MvvmCross Dynamic Text Value Conversion

Tags: windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

As far as I know, MvvmCross localization plugin provides "static" engine. I use the following binding as an example from Conference:

```
local:MvxBind="{'Text'{'Path':'TextSource','Converter':'Language','ConverterParameter':'SQLBitsXApp'}}"
```

I want to be able to change `SQLBitsXApp` to `SQLBitsXApp2` dynamically.
The goal is to find the localized text related to days enum.

Is there a way to do this dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - the default MvxLanguageConverter used in that binding is really there only for simple static text.

For more involved situations you will need to build your own converter for each case - but hopefully some of these will be reusable.

As a starting example, check out how the Conference sample displays tweet times using [TimeAgoConverter.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.Core/Converters/TimeAgoConverter.cs)

```
public class TimeAgoValueConverter
    : MvxBaseValueConverter
      , IMvxServiceConsumer<IMvxTextProvider>
{
    private IMvxTextProvider _textProvider;
    private IMvxTextProvider TextProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (_textProvider == null)
            {
                _textProvider = this.GetService<IMvxTextProvider>();
            }
            return _textProvider;
        }
    }

    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var when = (DateTime)value;

        string whichFormat;
        int valueToFormat;

        if (when == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            whichFormat = "TimeAgo.Never";
            valueToFormat = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            var whenUtc = when.ToUniversalTime();
            var difference = (DateTime.UtcNow - whenUtc).TotalSeconds;
            if (difference < 30.0)
            {
                whichFormat = "TimeAgo.JustNow";
               valueToFormat = 0;
            }
            // ... etc
        }

        var format = TextProvider.GetText(Constants.GeneralNamespace, Constants.Shared, whichFormat);
        return string.Format(format, valueToFormat);
    }
}
```

This is used in Android axml like in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/ListItem_Tweet.xml:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/TimeTextView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="10dip"
 android:textColor="@color/icongrey"
  local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Item.Timestamp','Converter':'TimeAgo'}}"
   />
```

Comment: I define a LocalizationBag class which contains LanguageBinder and a stringtofind property and add a new property CustomBag to the AboutViewModel to bind a TextView text to it. In MvxLanguageBinderConverter, I check whether value is IMvxLanguageBinder or LocalizationBag. If IMvxLanguageBinder, static engine is used, but if LocalizationBag, then static parameter is replaced by stringtofind to provide a dynamic engine. Tested with Conference sample, I will try to run with my enum now.

Comment: Would love to see you blog some of this somewhere ;)

Comment: No blog for me sorry! I will post a new comment feature to github with my code. My enum translation is working now with a little effort. Thank you for your help.